# Does what's on my shelves matter?

Tags: conveni-dream

I am mostly just picking the most expensive things I have space for. Is there some other strategy I should be using to attract customers and make a lot of money? Are there combos or anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there aren't any combos, you should pay attention to the prediction chart on your top screen. This shows the most probable distribution of customers visiting your convenience store.

Certain goods are preferred by certain customers and matching a customer to his/her preference will increase revenue and experience. When a match occurs, you'll see a gold coin pop up above their head (a normal purchase displays a silver coin).

For example, one of the initial items for sale is the Rice Ball. This food (found in Refrigerators) is preferred by Young Boys. You can see this preference by pressing and holding the stylus on the item while stocking and the relevant customer will be highlighted on the Prediction Chart. Young Boys are likely to buy the Rice Ball item and they will generate bonus experience for performing such a match.